# RTL Hardware Design Using VHDL, Example 7.1

Tags: vhdl, fpga

7.1 - Consider an Arithmetic Circuit that can perform four operations: a+b, a-b, a+1 and a-1, where a and b are 16-bit Unsigned Numbers and the desired operation is specified by a 2-bit Control Signal, ctrl.

Is it possible to design this circuit just with one adder without using sequential logic.

I designed this circuit with 2's complementary logic but i cannot add logic (a + (not b) + 1) just one adder without memory components

```
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

    entity Ex_7_1_b is
         generic( BUS_WIDTH : integer := 16 );
        port ( a : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
               b : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
               ctrl : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
               y : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0)
                );
    end Ex_7_1_b;

    architecture Behavioral of Ex_7_1_b is
        signal adder : unsigned(BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        signal mux_sign : unsigned(BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        signal mux_inp_sel : unsigned(BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        signal mux_val : unsigned(BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        signal result : unsigned(BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
    begin
        mux_val <= to_unsigned(0, mux_val'length) when ctrl(1) = '1' else to_unsigned(1, mux_val'length);
        mux_inp_sel <= mux_val when ctrl(0) = '1' else unsigned(b);
        mux_sign <= not (mux_inp_sel) when ctrl(1) = '1' else mux_inp_sel;

        result <= unsigned(a) + mux_sign;
        y <= std_logic_vector(result);

    end Behavioral;
```

Comment: You need one 16-bits adder with carry input: `s=x+y+c` where `x` and `y` are 16-bits unsigned and `c` is the one-bit carry input. As you already understood well, you will have to use multiplexers on front of your adder such that, depending on `ctrl` it computes `a+b+0`, `a+(not b)+1`, `a+1+0` or `a-1+0`. So, `x` is always equal to `a`, `y` equals `b`, `not b`, `x"0001"` (hexadecimal notation) or `x"ffff"` and `c`equals `'0'` or `'1'`. Code it exactly like this, using concurrent signal assignments and you will be done.

Comment: Thank you very much, i missed the carry in logic. This problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you found yourself is fine but it uses a 17-bits adder instead of a 16-bits one. With smart enough synthesizers it should not make any difference. Just for completeness here is another, 16-bits (and slightly simpler), solution:

```
architecture RTL of Ex_7_1_b is
    signal x, y0, y1: unsigned(g_BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
begin
    x   <= unsigned(i_a);
    y0  <= unsigned(i_b) when i_ctrl(1) = '0' else x"0001";
    y1  <= not y0 when i_ctrl(0) = '1' else y0;
    o_y <= std_logic_vector(x + y1 + i_ctrl(0));
end architecture RTL;
```

Note: this works only in VHDL 2008 where the addition of an `unsigned` and a `std_logic` is defined. If you must use an older version of the VHDL standard use the following, instead:

```
architecture RTL of Ex_7_1_b is
    signal x, y0, y1: unsigned(g_BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
    signal c: natural range 0 to 1;
begin
    x   <= unsigned(i_a);
    y0  <= unsigned(i_b) when i_ctrl(1) = '0' else x"0001";
    y1  <= not y0 when i_ctrl(0) = '1' else y0;
    c   <= 1 when i_ctrl(0) = '1' else 0;
    o_y <= std_logic_vector(x + y1 + c);
end architecture RTL;
```

Answer (score 2):

I designed this circuit with *Renaud Pacalet* contribute.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Ex_7_1_b is
    generic( g_BUS_WIDTH : integer := 16    );
    port ( 
            i_a : in  std_logic_vector (g_BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
            i_b : in  std_logic_vector (g_BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
            i_ctrl : in  std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
            o_y : out  std_logic_vector (g_BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0)
         );
end Ex_7_1_b;

architecture RTL of Ex_7_1_b is
    signal r_A_Ext, r_B_Ext : unsigned(g_BUS_WIDTH downto 0);
    signal r_Carry_In : std_logic;
    signal r_Adder : unsigned(g_BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
    signal w_Mux_Inv : unsigned(g_BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
    signal w_Mux_Sel : unsigned(g_BUS_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
    signal r_Result : unsigned(g_BUS_WIDTH downto 0);
begin
    r_A_Ext <= unsigned(i_a & '1');

    w_Mux_Sel <= to_unsigned(1, w_Mux_Sel'length) when i_ctrl(1) = '1' else unsigned(i_b);
    w_Mux_Inv <= not (w_Mux_Sel) when i_ctrl(0) = '1' else w_Mux_Sel;

    r_Carry_In <= '1' when i_ctrl(0) = '1' else '0';

    r_B_Ext <= w_Mux_Inv & r_Carry_In;

    r_Result <= r_A_Ext + r_B_Ext;
    o_y <= std_logic_vector(r_Result(g_BUS_WIDTH downto 1));
end RTL;
```